# How to mimic this text in Gimp?

Tags: fonts, gimp

I found this really cool text, and would like to use the style but for a different word. How can I do it in GIMP or pixlr.com?

[image]

Comment: What word were you wanting to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to find a similar font on [dafont.com > Comic Fonts](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=102&text=ZAP!&fpp=50) or [Blambot > Fonts](http://www.blambot.com/fonts_sfx.shtml). There are fonts out there where that style is already applied to the letters. In the case of the latter, the comic book fonts are sorted by purpose; you can find blocky overlapping letters under "sound effects" fonts.

Either way: Why re-invent the wheel, right? :)